# How to execute a script with Cron

Tags: xubuntu, scripts, cron

I would like to schedule a simple script to execute when the machine reboots. I have other schedule other commands in crontab using @reboot without any problems, but I can't seem to get my script to work. The script executes through the command line as well as when I double click on it. It is a permissions problem? The cron line I'm trying to use is: 
'@reboot /path/to/script.sh'

Answer (score 0):

I could be a problem of crons input buffer if your script does a lots of echos. Try the following:

```
@reboot /script.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```